# Possible Security concerns when exposing access through force.com sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, security

I have designed an unsubscribe functionality for Contacts in our org and I am a bit concerned about any potential security vulnerabilities this might lead to and how I can make the design more secure. I basically created a force.com site VF page where users can go and update their contact information or unsubscribe from emails using the Email Opt Out field. We send them an unsubscribe link with their contact Id in emails and when they try to open the link, the VF page first asks them to confirm their email id and then allows them access to unsubscribe or update their profile. Is this a secure design? Are their any potential security vulnerabilities I have created here? If yes, how could I resolve them?

Comment: If you want to be as CAN_SPAM compliant as possible there should be no login and everything should be on one page to unsubscribe: "you can’t charge a fee, require the recipient to give you any personally identifying information beyond an e-mail address, or make the recipient take any step other than sending a reply e-mail or visiting a single page on an Internet website as a condition for honoring an opt-out request." Just a thought. Although its debatable: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/09/log-in-to-unsubscribe-from-this-e-mail-annoying-possibly-illegal/ and not SF related

Comment: that was not what I was looking for, thank you anyways, but my question is more related to how vulnerable is my salesforce database with this design

Comment: Hence why it was a comment. Vulnerability depends on how you set up the security for the guest user

Comment: well I am only allowing access for the Contact and CampaignMember object but what I find a bit unsettling is to have to pass the contact Id with the link to an email address to access and update a lot of information through the site VF page. And my only way to validate the user is just the email address itself which doesn't feel very secure to me.

Comment: You could encrypt the Id and decrypt on the page